# What happens after AIR certificate expires?

Tags: air, code-signing

I have desktop AIR app which has been signed with a valid certificate from Chosensecurity. The certificate will expire later this month.

When it expires, will it affect the apps that has been already installed? And will I be able to keep letting users download/install this same version? Of course, if a new version of the app is released, I'd have to renew the certificate but for few months there will not be a new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you set a timestamp when you apply the codesigning, that particular module is good forever. (or at least until/if the certificate is revoked, not expired).
Expiring is a normal process that does not effect older signed modules.

Applying the timestamp looks something like this in Windows:

signtool.exe sign /v /f $(ProjectDir)..\DennisSign.pfx /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll $(TargetPath)